# javascript only runs once

Tags: javascript

This script only runs once. I click a button and it changes the menu. I click another button and it doesnt do anything. I tested this with both buttons going first than second.

```
function deelnemersmenu(optie) {
    if (optie == "deelnemers") {
        var menuHtml = "<div class='profielmenu_item_current' id='deelnemers_item_deelnemers' onclick='deelnemersmenu('deelnemers')'>Deelnemers</div><div class='profielmenu_item' id='deelnemers_item_bedrijven' onclick='deelnemersmenu('bedrijven')'>Bedrijven</div>";
    } else if (optie == "bedrijven") {
        var menuHtml = "<div class='profielmenu_item' id='deelnemers_item_deelnemers' onclick='deelnemersmenu('deelnemers')'>Deelnemers</div><div class='profielmenu_item_current' id='deelnemers_item_bedrijven' onclick='deelnemersmenu('bedrijven')'>Bedrijven</div>";
    }

    //when I leave the document etcera line out the script runs every time (getting the yeah message)
    document.getElementById('deelnemersmenu').innerHTML = menuHtml;
    alert("yeah");
}
```

Comment: you cant "insert" events in innerHTML

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change:

```
 ".. onclick='deelnemersmenu('deelnemers')' .. "
```

to

```
 ".. onclick='deelnemersmenu(\"deelnemers\")' .. "
```

and it will work. Be sure that you have change it on any position!

---

My Testcode:

```
<script>
var menuHtml = "<div class='profielmenu_item_current' id='deelnemers_item_deelnemers' onclick='deelnemersmenu(\"deelnemers\")'>Deelnemers</div><div class='profielmenu_item' id='deelnemers_item_bedrijven' onclick='deelnemersmenu(\"bedrijven\")'>Bedrijven</div>";

document.write(menuHtml);

function deelnemersmenu(x){
 alert(x);  
}
</script>
```

Comment: I knew it would be something stupid like that LOL

thanks man! it works now!